# Stash Destroys variable regardless of conditional

Tags: stash, conditionals, parse-order

I have the following at the top of one of my pages:

```
{if "{fn_zone}"!=""}
    {redirect="/store"}
{if:else}

{exp:stash:destroy name="delivery_day"}

.... More stuff ....

{/if}
```

However, what I'm finding is that regardless of the conditional the stash variable is *always* being destroyed.

I've even tried changing it to the following:

```
{if "{fn_zone}"!=""}
    {redirect="/store"}
{/if}
{if "{fn_zone}"==""}
    {exp:stash:destroy name="delivery_day"}
{/if}
```

Yet its still doing the same.

Can anyone advice how to deal with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quotes around {fn_zone} mean it's an advanced conditional which may be the problem.

Can you do:

```
{if fn_zone == ""}
...
{/if}
```

Or you may have to use the if:else plugin:

```
{exp:ifelse parse="inward"}  
    {if "{fn_zone}"!=""}
        {redirect="/store"}
    {if:else}

        {exp:stash:destroy name="delivery_day"}

    {/if}
{/exp:ifelse}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is because the conditional is an advanced one, and will be parsed after plugin tags (ie Stash) (ref [LOW's parse order PDF](http://loweblog.com/downloads/ee-parse-order.pdf)).

If the conditional was a simple one, this could work, but that depends on what {fn_zone} is. Only segment, embed, global variables are parsed as simple, and you have to write the left hand part of the conditional witout curly braces and string identifiers. If {fn_zone} is a global variable, something like this could do the trick:

```
{if fn_zone!=""}
    {redirect="/store"}
{/if}
{if fn_zone==""}
    {exp:stash:destroy name="delivery_day"}
{/if}
```

But, my goto solution in these cases is to use Croxtons Switchee or IfElse plugins, and have parse="inward" enabled. With switchee it would be something like this:

```
{exp:switchee variable="{fn_zone}" parse="inward"}
    {case value=""}
        {exp:stash:destroy name="delivery_day"}
    {/case}
    {case default="yes"}
        {redirect="/store"}
    {/case}
{/exp:switchee}
```

Hope that helps.